# Unable to click on ionic search icon to perform search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, searchbar

I have this code:

```
<ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <form id="search-form2" class="list">
      <label class="item item-input" id="search-search2">
        <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="{{staticLabels.whatToSearch}}" ng-model="vModel.searchText">
      </label>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
```

Search bar only works if someone press enter after typing keywords, but I want user to also click to search icon to perform the search.

I tried :

```
<i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon" ng-click="vModel.somefxn()"></i>
```

but it does not work.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Although the `ion-searchbar` directive is used for searching list, your version with icon & search input field should work fine. ng-click will work fine if you add cursor: pointer css property to i tag. You may be wondering it's just for showing hand icon for desktops on hover, but, it helps triggering touch event on mobiles, tabs even if you use conventional click event. So following should work fine:

```
<i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon search" ng-click="vModel.somefxn()"></i>
```

Where search class can be:

```
.search {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Padding will just help to increase clickable area for search icon.

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ogewrv

Comment: Thank you sir .. I tried the same the cursor works making search icon as a click entity but still the click wont initiate the function like codepen.

I tried 
It works only if I remove label somehow label blocks triggering the function
but without label I have no search area to type keywords
So I replaced the label with div tags and it started working :)